# Values of 'For-loop'

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I'm trying to find the biggest palindrome, which consists of a product of two 3-digit numbers.
When I enter the range (100,1000), the answer is: 580085
but if the range is: (600,1000), the answer is: 906609. Why do they change if the maximum value remains the same ?

```
Total = ''
for i in range(600,1000):
for z in range(600,1000):
    Pattern = str(i * z)
    nrettaP = Pattern[-1::-1]
    if Pattern == nrettaP:
        Total = Pattern
 print(Total)
```

Comment: Did my answer answer your question? Please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark if it did.

Answer (score 1):

The (100, 1000) loop is not really finding the biggest such number. Let's see what the loop actually checks. It checks:

- 100 * 100
- 100 * 101
- ...
- 100 * 998
- 100 * 999 <-- end of first iteration of outer loop
- 101 * 100 <-- start of second iteration of outer loop
- 101 * 101
- ...

Do you see how the values it checks is not always increasing? So the last value you checked that is a palindrome might not be the biggest.

Specifically, 580085 is 995 * 583, which is checked on the 894th iteration of the outer loop. 906609 is 993 * 913, which is checked on the 892th iteration of the outer loop, which is earlier.

A simple way to fix this is to add a `and (i * z) > Total` condition:

```
Total = 0
for i in range(100,1000):
    for z in range(100,1000):
        Pattern = str(i * z)
        nrettaP = Pattern[-1::-1]
        if Pattern == nrettaP and (i * z) > Total:
            Total = i * z
print(Total)
```

Also, the inner loop can start at `i` (`for z in range(i,1000):`), because you don't need to check `101 * 100`, once you have checked `100 * 101`.